# What hash function does Vertica use

Tags: hash, vertica

I'm looking for a way to assign devices to different groups for an A/B test.

To identify unique devices, we assign them with unique strings as keys - I have no control over this.

I thought about hashing, we're using a vertica DB and it has a built in function for hashing. But, because I don't know what kind of algorithm the function uses I can't reproduce it in the controller that assigns the devices to the A/B test groups.
I'm looking to apply the function on the unique device key.

I looked in the vertica documentation about the function but to no avail.

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HASH()` function is proprietary; however there are plans to make it open source in an upcoming release.

For segmentation, any SQL function can be used as long as it's immutable.